# How to add a list of image from drawable into an arraylist using ID from a string-arrays

Tags: android

Here's my code, please help check my problem

My string list that has the same name with the images in res drawable:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Intent Practice 1</string>
    <string-array name="list_name">
        <item>akiza</item>
        <item>blueeyes</item>
        <item>buster</item>
        <item>cyberdragon</item>
        <item>darklaw</item>
        <item>darkmagician</item>
        <item>darkmagiciangirl</item>
        <item>darkpaladin</item>
        <item>dragunity</item>
        <item>exodia</item>
        <item>gaia</item>
        <item>galaxyeyes</item>
        <item>harpies</item>
        <item>hope</item>
        <item>joey</item>
        <item>junk</item>
        <item>kaibaseto</item>
        <item>marik</item>
        <item>neos</item>
        <item>redeyes</item>
        <item>shaddoll</item>
        <item>shiningflare</item>
        <item>skulled</item>
        <item>spear</item>
        <item>stardust</item>
        <item>tourguide</item>
        <item>wingeddragon</item>
        <item>yamiyugi</item>
        <item>yudai</item>
        <item>yugimuto</item>
        <item>yuma</item>
        <item>yusei</item>
        <item>question</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I can set an ImageView using

```
ImageView imgQuestion, imgAnswer, temp;
static ArrayList<String> arrayName;
public static ArrayList<HinhAnh> arrayImg;
String questionName;
int REQUEST_CODE_IMG = 2703;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgAnswer = findViewById(R.id.imgAnswer);
    imgQuestion = findViewById(R.id.imgQuestion);

    String[] mangTen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_name);
    arrayName = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mangTen));
    arrayImg = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.shuffle(arrayName);
    **int idImg = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName.get(1), "drawable", getPackageName());
    imgQuestion.setImageResource(idImg);**
```

But I dont know how to add the list of images in to the arrayImg, I used:

```
    for (int position = 0; position < arrayName.size(); position++){
       int id = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName.get(position), "drawable", getPackageName());
       arrayImg.add(new HinhAnh(arrayName.get(position) + "", id));
       Toast.makeText(this, arrayImg.get(1).getTen() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I used Toast to check if I add successfully then the error showed out

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.intentpractice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
```

My class HinhAnh

```
public class HinhAnh {
    private String Ten;
    private int Hinh;

    public HinhAnh(String ten, int hinh) {
        Ten = ten;
        Hinh = hinh;
    }

    public String getTen() {
        return Ten;
    }

    public void setTen(String ten) {
        Ten = ten;
    }

    public int getHinh() {
        return Hinh;
    }

    public void setHinh(int hinh) {
        Hinh = hinh;
    }
}
```

They all lead to my adapter is null then I cannot fill my gridview at all. Please help!!

Edit:
I changed the line to get(position) then it worked. But it still showed error point to my adapter, here's my adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;
private List<HinhAnh> imageList;


public ImageAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<HinhAnh> imageList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.imageList = imageList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imgHinh;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        holder.imgHinh = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imgHinh.setImageResource(imageList.get(position).getHinh());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

and where I called it

```
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.imageline, MainActivity.arrayImg);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.intentpractice.Answers.onCreate(Answers.java:18)
```

Solved, I forgot returning getCount to array.size().
Thanks all!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue in your for loop for adding the images into the list.
For the position 0, there will be only one element in the arrayImg but you are calling arrayImg.get(1) which is causing `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

change that line to:

`for (int position = 0; position < arrayName.size(); position++){
       int id = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName.get(position), "drawable", getPackageName());
       arrayImg.add(new HinhAnh(arrayName.get(position) + "", id));
       Toast.makeText(this, arrayImg.get(position).getTen() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`

Comment: Got it, I made the array, then I realized that the issues came from my adapter.